# Account Relationship being set to blank by automated process when creating a contact

Tags: trigger, rest-api, automationstudio

Doesn't happen instantaneously, but after a minute or so, some automated process sets our new contact's account relationship record to blank.

[image]

We have disabled all automated process, triggers, apex and whatnot, but this still happens. Would love to know if there's a way to audit what's triggering this change? What can we do here?

Answer (score 0):

Set the field history tracking and check how it is getting change. It will give you more understanding to get started with full debuing

Comment: It did point me to a user named "automated process", now, why it's doing this, I still don't understand.

Comment: Automated Process is the running user of the code executed by a Platform Event Trigger / Change Event trigger. Check for those.

Comment: I've checked on them extensively and there are none. No apex class, no triggers, nothing that could explain this. Any other ideas I could try?

Comment: - Navigate to Debug Logs.
- Click New under User Trace Flags.
- For "Traced Entity Type", select "Automated Process"
This way you can debug what is happening with the automated process and identify the process causing this issue